# Multicolumn how to align the second column

Tags: tables, align, multicolumn

So I have something like this using `\multicolumn`:

```
        \begin{tabular}{lp{14cm}}
        \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}    

        \\ &\textbf{Left header 1}      \hspace{40pt}\textsc{Right header 1}\\
        \\&\textbf{Left header 2} \hspace{40pt}\textsc{Right header 2}\\


        \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}  
\end{tabular}
```

How do I make "Right header 1" and "Right header 2" to line up? I am now using the `\hspace` but I think there should be a better solution? I cannot just use the `&` before both Right headers.  So, doing this doesnt work:

```
\begin{tabular}{lp{14cm}}
        \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}    

        \\ &\textbf{Left header 1}      &\textsc{Right header 1}\\
        \\&\textbf{Left header 2} &\textsc{Right header 2}\\


        \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}  
    \end{tabular}
```

Please give me some help

A brief sketches:

```
---- align1 Left header 1------------| align2 Right header 1 
----- align1 some text---------------| align2 blank
------ align1 +bullet 1 in itemize---| align2 blank
------ align1 +bullet 2 in itemize---| align2 blank 
---- align1 Left header 2------------| align2 Right header 2
```

Comment: Could you please extend your code fragments a bit more? I assume this is used in some kind of tabular or similar environment. Could you please add, which and how your columns are defined? So far I am also not sure about why you use `\multicolumn`. Some background information on the purpose of the code might also be helpful.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{Left header 1} & \textsc{Right header 1}\\
\textbf{Left header 2} & \textsc{Right header 2}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` should work.

Comment: Thanks. But the reason why I am using `\multicolumn` is because I want to have an `itemize` environment.  Say for example between `Left header 1` and `Left header 2`.

Comment: `\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}    

\\ &\textbf{Left header 1}      \hspace{40pt}\textsc{Right header 1}\\   &\begin{itemize}....\end{itemize}
\\&\textbf{Left header 2} \hspace{40pt}\textsc{Right header 2}\\


\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} `

Comment: Basically, right after `Right header 1`, I can just do \\ & then do the itemize environment

Comment: Could you maybe add a sketch of the desired output to your question?

Comment: I just added a sketch, and I am sorry but I realized I forgot the add the tabular environment.  I just did in the edits

Comment: I use `align1`, `align2` to indicate the different alignment marker in my sketch.  The + are just `\item` in `\itemize` environment

Comment: Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BDR6.png

Comment: Yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example, I have used the `enumitem` package in order to define a new `tabitem` environment that can be sed inside of a `tabular` cell. You can use the value of  `leftmargin` to adjust the indentation of the items. Depending on the actual contents of your tabular you might also need to adjust the column widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep, leftmargin= 20pt ,label=\textbullet,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|l}
\textbf{Left header 1} & \textsc{Right header 1}\\
some text & \\
\begin{tabitem}
\item bullet 1 in itemize
\item bullet 2 in itemize
\end{tabitem} & \\
\textbf{Left header 2} & \textsc{Right header 2}\\
some text & \\
\begin{tabitem}
\item bullet 1 in itemize
\item bullet 2 in itemize
\end{tabitem} & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!